# Wait for chain of AJAX calls to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that calls other functions which have AJAX requests. I want all of the AJAX calls to complete before calling the last function. I initialize an array and need all of the AJAX calls to have successfully completed before going to the last step. When I run the code in the browser the console is showing the last method being called before the first AJAX call is completed. I've tried using `.done` however I'm still getting the same result.

```
function Search() {
       var userIds = [];
       var certName = $('#certificationName').val();
       var skillNumberOne = $('#skillName1').val();
       var skillNumberTwo = $('#skillName2').val();
       var skillNumberThree = $('#skillName3').val();
       var locale = $('#location').val();
       CertMatchResults(certName, userIds);
       SkillMatchResults(skillNumberOne, userIds);
       SkillMatchResults(skillNumberTwo, userIds);
       SkillMatchResults(skillNumberThree, userIds);
       LocationMatchResults(locale, userIds);
       console.log(userIds);
       DisplayMatches(userIds);
    }

    function CertMatchResults(certName, userIds) {
       if (certName == '') return;
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'matchCerts', certName: certName }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log("Cert Match >>> " + value.user_id);
             userIds.push(value.user_id);
          });
       }).done(function() {
          console.log("Cert match completed.");
       });
    }

    function SkillMatchResults(skillName, userIds) {
       if (skillName == '') return;
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'matchSkill', skillName: skillName }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log("Skill Match >>> " + value.user_id);
             userIds.push(value.user_id);
          });
       });
    }
... other calls below ... I can add them if needed
```

`DisplayMatches` needs all of the AJAX calls in each of the functions before it to complete.

Comment: [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

Comment: I think it's a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have all functions call the `DisplayMatches` when they are done and check the `userIDs` array if it is complete ... and when it is you know all is done so you just run it, if not, exit

Answer (score 2):

You should create a chain of [deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Each ajax call returns Deferred object and then you can gather them in [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function and invoke the last function once all the ajax calls resolved their promises in **jQuery.then** function.

```
$.when( $.getJson("url1"), $.getJson("url2") ).then(function( valueFromUrl1, valueFromUrl2 ) {
  functionThatShouldBeInvokedLast();
});
```